# Camel Log Component

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel

I'm looking for a logging solution that is based on `SLF4J` so I can bind to any underlying implementation I want at runtime (for right now I'm thinking `log4j`). Since I am planning to have my backend routed via Apache Camel, I figured Camel must have some solution for logging.

It does - [here](http://camel.apache.org/log.html).

But from that page description I can't tell if `camel-log` is for pushing internal (Camel) messages (errors, exceptions, infos, etc.) to SLF4J, or for me to use as a SLF4J "wrapper", or both.

Hence my question: **is `camel-log` for enabling Camel messaging (so I can see what Camel is doing under the hood) or is it a component that pushes my application's messages onto a route? Or both?!?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camel log component (http://camel.apache.org/log.html) is for logging exchanges. In latest versions of Camel it uses SFL4J so you could choose underlying logging implementation in usual SFL4J way.

You could enable 'trace' on Camel context to 'see what Camel is doing under the roof'.

For your own logging you could just use SLF4J inside your code as usual.

Comment: Thanks maximdim - but I'm still a little confused, particularly with your last sentence there: "*For your own logging you could just use SLF4J inside your code as usual.*" I am looking for a single logging solution, and am wondering if I can use `camel-log` to handle **both** Camel's internal logging as well as my app's logging. From your last sentence, it sounds like I can't have my application send/publish messages to a `camel-log` endpoint, which (like you mentioned) uses SLF4J. The point is, I don't want half my code to invoke SLF4J, and half my code to use `camel-log`. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, if you stick with SLF4J your code and Camel will be using 'single logging solution' in a sense that both what your app writes to log and what Camel writes to log will be going through SLF4J, if that's what you mean. 'camel-log' is primarily for logging the exchanges in Camel routes (for debug, audit, etc) and it also uses SLF4J internally. You might or might not use camel-log in your routes, depending on your requirements but that doesn't change how Camel uses logging internally.